# Import Error in rc.local for open cv2 module

Tags: python, linux, opencv, ubuntu, boot

My `python 3.6` script works fine when running in the terminal once logged in but I’m having an `import cv2 error (module not found)` when trying to run it in `rc.local`. So far in that file I just have `python /home/user/face_recog.py` before `exit 0`. Maybe it has something to do with not using the `opencv` path? Does anyone know how to fix this import error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install the module with sudo?
If you install a module via pip without sudo it's only available for the current user, rc.local uses root, so you need to add sudo in your installing command.